# Revoking iOS Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, distribution

[I've checked similar posts and my question differs slightly from others in that we have multiple apps signed under one certificate]

We've been commissioned to work on an existing iOS app for a client and now need to distribute it to the app store using their certificate. The problem is that the certificate wasn't generated by us so we do not have the private key (.p12 file). Assuming that we can't get this, I believe the only option is to revoke the existing distribution certificate and create a new one...so my question is:

Q1) The client has 3 existing apps on the app store all signed under this existing Distribution Certificate. If we revoke the existing certificate and create a new one will it break the existing apps?

Q2) Presumably the 'Company' name for your app in the app store is taken from the distribution certificate? i.e. If I signed the app using our certificate instead, would our company name appear above the app instead of the clients?

Thanks!!

Neil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same dilemma.

Q1) It is ok to do this, it will not break the existing apps. Just go ahead and create a new one right after you do it.

Q2) The name will not be affected, you set this yourself in iTunes connect when you submit the app.